# appending value to a variable on the next line in php

Tags: php

Please, how do I append a value to an existing string? But only add the value to the next two lines `"/n"`

```
$var = "Hello People" ;
$nextline = "I want this message on the next line" ;
$msg = $var . $nextline ;
```

I know that `"<br>"` will work but am sending respoJSONback to json data and "`<br>`" will remain `<br>` when executed.
`nl2br()` seems will work but I don't know how to implement that.

Please any help will be appreciated
I tried

```
$msg = $var . "/n" . $nextline ;
```

but didnt work(edited)

Thank you.

Comment: `\n` if you use pre tag, or `<br>`

Comment: If you're seeing `<br>` in the output on the web page, the Javascript is presumably using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, so it doesn't parse HTML markup. This makes it difficult for the server to send layout information.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas Please can you send me a sample code. Already tried messing with \n but no success

Comment: How are you appending this? You meantioned JSON back, so does that mean its happening in an ajax request for more data? You could append the needed newline/break within the javascript part that appends to an element content.